# JavaScript Coding Assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like some help making the "Show Picture" button show/hide the picture whenever it is clicked. I am trying to do it using an If/Else statement as it is for a school project and is required. I cannot figure it out for some reason and assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showA').on('click', function() {
    $('#house1').css('opacity', 1).fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#resetA').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
  });

  $('#submitA').click(function() {
    window.alert("You will be contacted through email shortly in order to process your payment method for the home in Chatham, MA. Thank you for choosing Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes!");
  });

  $('#showB').on('click', function() {
    $('#house2').css('opacity', 1).fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#resetB').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
  });

  $('#submitB').click(function() {
    window.alert("You will be contacted through email shortly in order to process your payment method for the home in Wellfleet, MA. Thank you for choosing Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes!");
  });

  $('#showC').on('click', function() {
    $('#house3').css('opacity', 1).fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#resetC').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
  });

  $('#submitC').click(function() {
    window.alert("You will be contacted through email shortly in order to process your payment method for the home in Dennis, MA. Thank you for choosing Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes!");
  });

  $('#showD').on('click', function() {
    $('#house4').css('opacity', 1).fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#resetD').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
  });

  $('#submitD').click(function() {
    window.alert("You will be contacted through email shortly in order to process your payment method for the home in Provincetown, MA. Thank you for choosing Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes!");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  padding: 29px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

div {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 267px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/finalproject.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/finalproject.js">
  </script>
  <title>Final Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes</h1>
  </center>

  <div>
    <form id="chatham">
      <label><b><u>Chatham, MA</u></b></label><br>
      <label><b>$300 a Day</b></label><br>
      <label>Name:</label><br>
      <input name="nameA" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Email Address:</label><br>
      <input name="emailA" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
      <input name="phoneA" type="text" /><br>
      <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
      <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
      <input id="showA" type="button" value="Show Picture">
      <input id="submitA" type="button" value="Submit">
      <input id="resetA" type="button" value="Reset">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form id="wellfleet">
      <label><b><u>Wellfleet, MA</u></b></label><br>
      <label><b>$250 a Day</b></label><br>
      <label>Name:</label><br>
      <input name="nameB" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Email Address:</label><br>
      <input name="emailB" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
      <input name="phoneB" type="text" /><br>
      <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
      <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
      <input id="showB" type="button" value="Show Picture">
      <input id="submitB" type="button" value="Submit">
      <input id="resetB" type="button" value="Reset">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form id="dennis">
      <label><b><u>Dennis, MA</u></b></label><br>
      <label><b>$350 a Day</b></label><br>
      <label>Name:</label><br>
      <input name="nameC" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Email Address:</label><br>
      <input name="emailC" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
      <input name="phoneC" type="text" /><br>
      <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
      <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
      <input id="showC" type="button" value="Show Picture">
      <input id="submitC" type="button" value="Submit">
      <input id="resetC" type="button" value="Reset">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form id="provincetown">
      <label><b><u>Provincetown, MA</u></b></label><br>
      <label><b>$300 a Day</b></label><br>
      <label>Name:</label><br>
      <input name="nameD" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Email Address:</label><br>
      <input name="emailD" type="text" /><br>
      <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
      <input name="phoneD" type="text" /><br>
      <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
      <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
      <input id="showD" type="button" value="Show Picture">
      <input id="submitD" type="button" value="Submit">
      <input id="resetD" type="button" value="Reset">
    </form>
  </div>

  <img id="house1" src="images/chatham.jpg" />
  <img id="house2" src="images/wellfleet.jpg" />
  <img id="house3" src="images/dennis.jpg" />
  <img id="house4" src="images/provincetown.jpg" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I am trying to do it using an If/Else` - there is no `if` or `else` in the code you posted, so, you're not trying that at all

Comment: Looks like it's working for me, the image shows when you click the button, but it doesn't work in your demo because the images don't exist. Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the opacity to 0 first for all the images,then show the right image

```
$('img').css('opacity',0);
```

```js
$('.show').on('click', function() {
  $('img').css('opacity', 0);
  var ind = $(this).closest('.house').parent().index();
  $('img').eq(ind).css('opacity', 1).fadeIn('slow');
});

$('.reset').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
});

$('.submit').click(function() {
  window.alert("You will be contacted through email shortly in order to process your payment method for the home in Chatham, MA. Thank you for choosing Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes!");
});
```

```css
img {
  padding: 29px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

div {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 267px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <h1>Bazegian Cape Cod Rental Homes</h1>
</center>

<div>
  <form class="house">
    <label><b><u>Chatham, MA</u></b></label><br>
    <label><b>$300 a Day</b></label><br>
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input name="nameA" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Email Address:</label><br>
    <input name="emailA" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
    <input name="phoneA" type="text" /><br>
    <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
    <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
    <input class="show" type="button" value="Show Picture">
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    <input class="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form class="house">
    <label><b><u>Wellfleet, MA</u></b></label><br>
    <label><b>$250 a Day</b></label><br>
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input name="nameB" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Email Address:</label><br>
    <input name="emailB" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
    <input name="phoneB" type="text" /><br>
    <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
    <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
    <input class="show" type="button" value="Show Picture">
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    <input class="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form class="house">
    <label><b><u>Dennis, MA</u></b></label><br>
    <label><b>$350 a Day</b></label><br>
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input name="nameC" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Email Address:</label><br>
    <input name="emailC" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
    <input name="phoneC" type="text" /><br>
    <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
    <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
    <input class="show" type="button" value="Show Picture">
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    <input class="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <form class="provincetown">
    <label><b><u>Provincetown, MA</u></b></label><br>
    <label><b>$300 a Day</b></label><br>
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input name="nameD" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Email Address:</label><br>
    <input name="emailD" type="text" /><br>
    <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
    <input name="phoneD" type="text" /><br>
    <label>How many days would you like to rent?</label><br>
    <select>
     <option value="5-10">5-10 Days</option>
     <option value="6-7">10-15 Days</option>
     <option value="8-9">15-20 Days</option>
  </select>
    <input class="show" type="button" value="Show Picture">
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    <input class="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>

<img class="img" src="images/chatham.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="images/wellfleet.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="images/dennis.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="images/provincetown.jpg" />
```

ps: you seriously need to DRY your code